# Are there any good external trackpad devices that work well with Ubuntu?

Tags: touchpad

Are there any good external trackpads that work well with Ubuntu? So far, I've found that the Logitech T650 should work, but it seems to be discontinued and out of stock in most places. I've got RSI in both of my arms, making me unable to use a normal mouse, and I'm considering getting an external trackpad to use with the separate keyboard (as I'm not a fan of RollerMouse and similar devices). Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a hardware recommendation question.

Comment: Sure, I won't argue with that. Could you please give me a hint as to where I might turn for help, though? I've really struggled to find someone to ask, and this was my last resort.